# How to change a buttons state from disabled to active when an option is selected in an OptionMenu Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

I'm trying to change the button state when an option is selected in the option menu, but nothing is changing. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

def setLabel():
    changed.set("Active")
    
def changeState():
    pick = choose.get()
    if (pick == "op2"):
        button['state'] = button.ACTIVE
        button.config(text = "ACTIVE")
    else:
        button['state'] = app.DISABLED
        button.config(text = "Disabled")

app = Tk()
app.resizable(40,40)

choose = StringVar()
choose.set("op1")
options = OptionMenu(app, choose, "op1", "op2")
options.pack()


button = Button(app, text = "Disabled", state = DISABLED, command = setLabel)
button.pack()

changed = StringVar()
label = Label(app, textvariable = changed, font = ("helvetica", 10))
label.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ive added an answer do let me know

Comment: Ah thanks for your help. I only just saw this after I had posted I had figured it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
def changeState():
    pick = choose.get()
    if (pick == "op2"):
        button['state'] = ACTIVE #means active state
        button.config(text = "ACTIVE")
    else:
        button['state'] = DISABLED #means disabled state
        button.config(text = "Disabled")
```

Also your not calling your function, so to call it and make the effect active, add a command argument onto your optionmenu, like:

```
options = OptionMenu(app, choose, "op1", "op2",command=lambda _:changeState())
```

Using `lambda _:` because optionmenu command expect a tkinter variable to be passed on, so as to avoid that. You could also have a parameter for your function, but if your calling your function somewhere else, your gonna have to pass in a argument or your could also use parameter like `point=None` and get rid of the `lambda`.

Hope this cleared the errors, do let me know if any doubts.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Edit: I changed line 9 slightly, removing button.active and replacing with NORMAL and this worked.

```
from tkinter import *

def setLabel():
    changed.set("Active")
    
def changeState(*args):
    pick = choose.get()
    if (pick == "op2"):
        button['state'] = NORMAL
        button.config(text = "ACTIVE")
    else:
        button['state'] = DISABLED
        button.config(text = "Disabled")

app = Tk()
app.resizable(40,40)

choose = StringVar()
choose.set("op1")
options = OptionMenu(app, choose, "op1", "op2")
choose.trace("w", changeState)
options.pack()


button = Button(app, text = "Disabled", state = DISABLED, command = setLabel)
button.pack()

changed = StringVar()
label = Label(app, textvariable = changed, font = ("helvetica", 10))
label.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here. Please [edit] it and say what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: It's a code-only answer to your own question, but you have said what you "got" or what's different from the code in your question — so it makes it less enlightening to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `command=changeState` in `OptionMenu(...)` to call `changeState()` whenever the `options` is changed:

```py
def changeState(pick):
    if pick == "op2":
        button['state'] = ACTIVE
        button.config(text = "ACTIVE")
    else:
        button['state'] = DISABLED
        button.config(text = "Disabled")

...

options = OptionMenu(app, choose, "op1", "op2", command=changeState)
```

Comment: Hmmm, the command of optionmenu takes an argument of the tkinter variable right? So this will produce error. You might want to use lambda

Comment: @CoolCloud Did you try it? The callback will be passed the selected item.

Comment: Actually i did and got the error - Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974203/optionmenu-command-function-requires-argument)

Comment: @CoolCloud My version of `changeState()` has an argument, so it is the same as what you said `lambda _`.  So I don't know why you propose to use lambda.

Comment: Oh i dint notice that the parameter, yes your correct.