# Tkinter OptionMenu: how to pass a value with a lambda function?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, optionmenu

In Button, why can the variable TEXT be passed to print_text() with a lambda function, but not in OptionMenu? When the program is run and a value is selected from the option menu, the following error is displayed:

> TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

How could I pass TEXT to print_text() with a lambda function in OptionMenu?

Which confuses me even more, why does Pylint show the following errors for button = Button(...) and option_menu = OptionMenu(...) and how can it be resolved:

> "Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return".

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, OptionMenu, StringVar

def print_text(some_text):
    print(some_text)

main_window = Tk()

# Button
TEXT = "This works"
button = Button(main_window, text="Print to console",
                command=lambda: print_text(TEXT)).pack() # works

# OptionMenu
selected_value_option_menu = StringVar(main_window)
OPTIONS = ["one", "two", "three"]
option_menu = OptionMenu(main_window, selected_value_option_menu, *OPTIONS,
                         command=lambda: print_text(TEXT)).pack() # does not work

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can find the answer visiting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974203/optionmenu-command-function-requires-argument) page.

Comment: Great. Thank you.